# React native crash on cancel share action

Tags: react-native

React native app crash when we do not finish share process, with following error.
There is no any solution to solve the issue without upgrading react-native version. 
On test flight app just crash.

Any idea how to handle that?

```
    Illegal callback invocation from native module. This callback type only permits a single invocation from native code.

    RCTFatal
    RCTCheckCallbackMultipleInvocations
    __41-[RCTModuleMethod processMethodSignature]_block_invoke_3
    __89-[RCTActionSheetManager showShareActionSheetWithOptions:failureCallback:successCallback:]_block_invoke
    __68-[UIActivityViewController _cleanupActivityWithSuccess:items:error:]_block_invoke
    -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:]
    __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke.503
    -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:]
    -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:]
    -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:]
    -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:]
    -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:]
    -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:]
    -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:]
    CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*)
    _dispatch_client_callout
    _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
    __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
    __CFRunLoopRun
    CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    GSEventRunModal
    UIApplicationMain
    main
    start


And here is how I use Share module.
```

```
import {
    Share,
} from 'react-native';

await Share.share({
    message: msg,
    url: 'https://www.example.com/',
    title: 'Wow, did you see that?'
}, {
    excludedActivityTypes: [
        'com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToTwitter'
    ]
})
```

React native version is:
`"react-native": "0.46.4"`

[image: Reac]

Comment: I ended up, using react-native-share lib instead of build one